# Como percorrer Enum em Java

Tags: java, enums

Tenho o seguinte Enum:

```
public enum TipoPokemon {

    FIRE("FIRE"),
    WATER("WATER"),
    GRASS("GRASS"),
    ELECTRIC("ELECTRIC"),
    ICE("ICE"),
    DARK("DARK"),
    GHOST("GHOST"),
    FAIRY("FAIRY"),
    PSYCHIC("PSYCHIC"),
    DRAGON("DRAGON"),
    POISON("POISON"),
    GROUND("GROUND"),
    ROCK("ROCK"),
    NORMAL("NORMAL"),
    BUG("BUG"),
    FIGHTING("FIGHTING"),
    STEEL("STEEL"),
    FLYING("FLYING");

    private String nome;

    private TipoPokemon(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Preciso percorrer cada um destes valores em uma outra classe para fazer uma comparação de valores. Como posso fazer para percorrer cada valor do Enum e comparar com uma string x ?

Comment: @renan Vou ter um método x que vai receber um texto como parâmetro...Dentro deste texto vou verificar se algum dos valores do enum está entre o texto, entendeu ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para obter todos os valores que existe no enum, faça o seguinte:

```
List<TipoPokemon> list = Arrays.asList(TipoPokemon.values());

ou

List<TipoPokemon> list = new ArrayList<TipoPokemon>(EnumSet.allOf(TipoPokemon.class));
```

Com a lista já populada, você só precisa percorrer e comparar

ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    boolean exemplo = list.get(i).name() == "X";
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Tenho um exemplo que pode te ajudar:

```
public enum AlgarismoRomano {

    I(1), V(5), X(10), L(50), C(100), D(500), M(1000);

    private int numeroArabico;

    private AlgarismoRomano(int numeroArabico) {
        this.numeroArabico = numeroArabico;
    }

    public static int retornarNumeroArabico(char numeroRomano) {
        return valueOf(String.valueOf(numeroRomano)).numeroArabico;
    }

    public static List<Character> getAlgarismosRomanos() {
        List<Character> algarismos = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (AlgarismoRomano algarismo : values())
            algarismos.add(algarismo.toString().toCharArray()[0]);

        return algarismos;
    }

}
```

O método `getAlgarismosRomanos` faz isso... itera entra o array para pegar o valor do meu enum. Obs: para interar no enum é `Enum.values()` (o `values` é um array de Enum).

Comment: E como isso resolveria o problema da pergunta? Reli a resposta e não consegui sequer relacionar como solução.